# Manually trigger change in Angular when form is submitted from a sibling component

Tags: angular

I have two **sibling** components, one of which is a modal with a form (to add/edit users) and the other is a table of users. When a user is added or updated, I need to **sibling** table to be updated.

I have tried to trigger the change in my `onSubmit()` in the modal/form component, but it does not seem to update the **sibling** component:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

and then:

```
constructor(
    private change: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}
```

and finally in the `onSubmit()`:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.users.postUser(this.userForm.value).subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.modalRef.hide();
            this.userForm.reset();
            this.change.detectChanges();
        },
        (err) => {
            this.apiHandler.errorHandler(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: how about using service (observable and subject )? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: If you add all source codes, it would be better to understand. I usually update users table (get users function) info again after some changes of user info which run by https services.

Comment: If you have the shared data in a service, change detection will pick up the changes and automatically update the UI with any updated data (no subject needed).

Comment: @DeborahK it's not really "shared data" the form is using an api controller for createUser & updateUser, while the table is subscribed to the getAllUsers controller. I tried just calling the getAllUsers controller again when the form was submitted to see if that would trigger the change in the table's subscription, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `subject` in the form component and subscribe to that subject in the table component. Emit an observable when a user is added.

Answer (score 0):

I just built some code to demonstrate this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take5

My UI looks like this. It's movies, but should be close to what you are doing to manage users:

[image]

[image]

When a movie is added, it automatically appears in the list on the left. This is all done with a single movie data service and getters and setters. (No subject/behavior subject.)

Comment: Broken link :) .

Comment: The "best practice" for this scenario has changed to a more RxJS declarative approach. See this for details: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS/tree/master/APM-Final

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger **change detection**, on slibing components you can use **ngDoCheck** lyfecycle hook.

**ngDoCheck** lifecycle hook that is called when Angular dirty checks a directive.

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slibing-components-cd)

[Official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck)

But this lifecycle hook is used to check changes of @Input properties that Angular can't or won't detect on its own. For example, if you pass object to input bindings and change it's properties on parent component. And child component used **changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush**

[Code example 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slibing-components-cd-sp2vhr)